# performance on this substring search

Tags: c#, performance

I have the code below that gets hit several hundred times per second. I'm wondering what I can do to improve performance. It seems that there should be some way to build up a substring index. Is there some existing examples of that or an explanation on how to do this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Asi.Server.Interfaces.History;

namespace Asi.Server.History.AssetHistory
{
    public class TelemetrySubscriptionFilter: ITelemetryLogFilter, ITelemetryLogAutosubscriber
    {
        private readonly List<string> _shouldNotLogs = new List<string>
        {
            "Local Position Service",
            "Global Position Service",
            "PositionGroup.",
            "DKS/"
        };

        public bool ShouldNotLog(string telemetryName)
        {
            float period;
            if (ShouldAutoSubscribe(telemetryName, out period))
                return false;

            // telemetryName is longer than our filter texts
            return _shouldNotLogs.Any(s => telemetryName.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0);
        }

        private readonly List<string> _shouldAutoSubscribe = new List<string>
        {
            "Manual Mode",
            "Autonomous Driven",
            "Battery Voltage",
            "RPM",
            "Engine On",
            "Parking Brake",
            "Gear",
            "Stopping Distance",
            "Ready For Motion",
            "GPS Correction Sent",
            "Setpoint",
            "Dead Reckon",
            "VCU uC",
            "Feedback",
            "Off Path",
            "RMS",
            "Yaw Rate",
            "Stop Enabled",
            "Arbiter",
            "Velocity Error",
            "Processor"
        };

        public bool ShouldAutoSubscribe(string telemetryName, out float period)
        {
            period = 0.375f; // chosen somewhat arbitrarily
            return _shouldAutoSubscribe.Any(s => telemetryName.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The two readonly Lists should be `static`, but that won't affect the speed.

Comment: What's wrong with `String.Contains()`? It already performs an ordinal comparison.

Comment: You might be able to get better performance using the [Commentz-Walter algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commentz-Walter_algorithm) or the [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) of `telemetryName`.

Comment: "suffix array" appears to be the phrase that I needed for the web search. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried making a `Regex` that matches any of the strings in the list mentioned? If you create the regex in advance, it will probably be faster than looping over the list of strings. Convert the list into the regex using

```
Regex regex = new Regex(String.Join('|',list.Select(x=>Regex.Escape(x))));
```

then check using `regex.IsMatch(telemetryName)`.

References:

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
  `Regex`
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
  `String.Join`
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `Regex.Escape()`
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `Regex.IsMatch()`

Comment: Compiled Regex seems to be 4x faster. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: and of course, that's supposed to be a `private static readonly` class member, not a local variable.

Comment: Right. And I pass it the compiled flag (as a static).

Comment: Ah, `RegexOptions.Compiled`. I'll have to remember that needs to be provided explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

As with every performance question: **run your code through a profiler**

That said, your `ShouldNotLog` method can be simplified.  There is not much reason to check your auto subscribe list prior to checking your suppress list:

- _shouldNotLogs is a shorter list
- presumably, none of the strings in _shouldNotLogs should exist in _shouldAutoSubscribe

As a result, checking _shouldAutoSubscribe only adds extra work.  The only times you perform fewer operations is if the input name matches one of the first three elements in _shouldAutoSubscribe.  It's a wash at four.  Anything else is extra work.

This leaves us with the following:

```
    public bool ShouldNotLog(string telemetryName)
    {
        return _shouldNotLogs.Any(s => telemetryName.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0);
    }
```

Next, for readability, I would instead use `string.Contains`.  If you check the .NET source, `string.Contains` calls `string.IndexOf` internally with an Ordinal check, so it is effectively the same thing, but it declares your intent far better:

```
    public bool ShouldNotLog(string telemetryName)
    {
        return _shouldNotLogs.Any(s => telemetryName.Contains(s));
    }
```

If possible, though, an even better way of doing it would be to extract your telemetry names to some numerical ID and use enums or ints.  Number comparison will be **far** quicker than string comparison.  However, you state that your input names are superstrings of those appearing in your lists, so I don't know if that is feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the Contains method. I hadn't expected it to be Ordinal.

Comment: @Brannon yeah - I wasn't 100% sure about it, so I looked it up.  Microsoft released most/all the framework code over the Build conference this year.  You can reference it at the [sourceof.net](http://sourceof.net) page.

Comment: The docs for `Contains()` indicate that it uses an ordinal compare, though I don't know how long that tidbit has been included.